# Vertical align text in cell

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to align text in a cell?

In my example I want to align hours and city centrally like this:

[image]

[PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/uYYPYbeTiBYEx0ud0wBF?p=preview)

```css
#presentation {
    background-color: #dedede;
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-right: 50px;
}

#offers h1 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #666666;
}

#offers h1 em {
    color: #4598d1;
    font-style: normal;
}

.offers {
    padding: 25px 50px;
    width: 50%;
    margin: auto;
}

.offers button {
    background-color: #dddddd;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #868686;
    border: #868686;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
}

.offers .right {
    float: right;
    width: 100px;
}

.offers table {
    background-color: #DEDEDE;
    text-align: left;
    float: left;
}

.offers .tittle {
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #666666;
    font-family: 'Arial Normal', 'Arial';
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.offers th {
    font-family: 'Arial Normal', 'Arial';
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 11px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.offers table th .fistClass {
    font-family: 'Arial Gras', 'Arial';
    font-weight: 700;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #669900;
    text-align: center;
}

.offers table .td {
    background-color: #ffffff;

}

.offers .departureTime {
    color: #35A6F4;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.offers .arrivalTime {
    color: #35A6F4;
    font-size: 11px;
}

.offers .originStation {
    font-family: 'Arial Gras', 'Arial';
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 11px;
}

.offers .destinationStation {
    font-family: 'Arial Gras', 'Arial';
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 11px;
}

.offers .duration {
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #666666;

}

.offers .priceFirstClass {
    color: #7ABB00;
    text-align: right;
    font-family: 'Arial Gras', 'Arial';
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.offers .minPrice {

}

.offers .lastPlaces {

}

.offers .unavailable {
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #E4E4E4;
    text-align: center;
}

.offers .foo {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    width: auto;
}

.offers p.espacement_important {
    margin: 5px 0;
}
.offers span{
    padding-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="presentation">
    <section>
        <div class="offers">
            <table border="0">
            <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                        <div>
                            <p>
                            <span class="departureTime">03h00</span>
                             <span>New-York</span>
                            </p>
                             <p>
                                <span class="arrivalTime">15h00</span>
                                <span>Bahamas</span>
                            </p>

                            <p class="duration"><span >8h00</span>
                                <span>2 correspond.</span>
                                <span>A380</span>
                            </p>
                          </div>
                        </td>
                      <td class="unavailable">indisponible</td>

                    <td><input type="radio" />
                        <label >10.00 €</label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <label >50.00 €</label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you put your code inline using the code editor? Not everyone can access plunker :(

Comment: Table cell-content is aligned in the middle by default and the spans just need a vertical-align and a line-height and you're done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code.

HTML

```
<div id="presentation">
<section>
    <div class="offers">
        <table class="locationtable" width="100%;" cellpadding="0">
            <tr>
                <td width="50%"><span class="departureTime">03h00</span></td>
                <td width="50%"><span>New-York</span></td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td class="duration">8h00</td>
                <td><span>Bahamas</span></td>
            </tr>

        </table>
    </div>
</section>
```

CSS

```
.locationtable{
    width: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #eee;
}
table td{
    padding: 5px 10px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}
.departureTime,
.duration{
    color: blue;
}
```

[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/shanidkv/odutus1f/)

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do, is to force the text on a unique line.
I can think now of two solutions to proceed so.

The first one, would be to give to the cell that contains your text a minimum width that would always allow the text to display on one line, but, what if a new longer station name is created forward ?

The second solution is to force the text on one line with a css property call "white-space", and, in a table cell it will automatically resize the "td" to fit your text :

```
.offers td:first-child p{
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```